# Organizar informacion en plot de dataframe python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente plot:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que primero aparezca enero, luego febrero y asi, que no se organice en orden alfabetico.

este es el codigo para generar la imagen.

```
%matplotlib inline
print("Analizando datos...")

TiempoA = datetime.datetime.now()
df["DATEOTRO"] = df["DATE"].apply(OrganizarPorMes)

print("Datos Analizados...")

print("Creando Grafica...")
plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
plt.plot(df.groupby("DATEOTRO")["DATEOTRO"].count())
plt.show()

TiempoTotal = datetime.datetime.now() - TiempoA
print("Grafica Creada. Tiempo: " + str(int(TiempoTotal.total_seconds())) + " seg...")
```

Answer (score 1):

No conozco los datos de entrada pero usando estos:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

fechas = [datetime(2020, x+1, 1) for x in range(12)] 

datos = [randint(0,100) for x in range(12)]

data = {"fechas": fechas, "datos": datos}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ["fechas", "datos"])
```

Obtenemos un dataframe con fechas y un valor asociado. Lo mejor es graficarlo usando el objecto fecha completo y modificar el eje con el formato que necesitas, por ejemplo usar `mdates.DateFormatter('%B')` para que el eje use los nombres de los meses:

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# graficar usando las fechas completas para manetener el orden
plt.plot(df["fechas"], df["datos"])

# indicar que quieres usar todos los puntos (para que aparezcan todos los meses)
plt.xticks(df["fechas"])

# establecer el formato del eje x (mostrar el nombre del mes)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%B'))

plt.show()
```

De esta manera obtenemos el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]